# How to call the REST api and get the response and show it in HTML page

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I just have a page which has text field and search button. When an user entered some numbers (typed value = 1)and clicked search button it needs to call the REST (JAVA) client and get the response and show case it into front end.

***Sample Back end table:***

```
Count | Name  | Address
  1   |  XXX  |  AAA
  2   |  YYY  |  BBB
  3   |  ZZZ  |  CCC
```

if the user entered 1 then it should return the name and address details of the given input which is handled in REST (JAVA). But It should be displayed in html page.

The REST (JAVA) client will query the input value (text field) against back end and return the response. I just want to show case this into client side (HTML).

Is this possible to done by node.js/Javascript?

I just need some idea to kick start my application. It would be very helpful if you share the ideas, and efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's not clear to me how NodeJS enters the picture. There are many ways this can be done on the client side (I assume browser, but because you said NodeJS, maybe it's an Electron app?) and as asked this is a pretty broad question.

Comment: Have you put any effort into researching an answer? Where is your code from your attempts so far?

Comment: I just need some input on this. I'm not sure how can I start that requirement. Even I just wanna try that my self. So I just asked some basic example to achieve this. If I get idea then I will start developing the application.

Comment: @Dave  I'm not sure node.js gonna help me on this. But I just heard that Express.js gonna help me to call REST service and get the response back. I'm completely new to node.js world. Im not sure whether it will fit in for this requirement.

Comment: You can call any service with (most) any language/framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOM element rendering on AJAX call in jquery.

Example -

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

You will get data in JSON format, then you can render the JSON objects according to your choice.

I can make it more clear to you if you have data-url or any web-service where your data is present.
I can create a complete code to you for that.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for yours input.